# How to Scale SPICE Matrix so LU-decomposition doesn't Fail

Tags: boost, simulation

I am implementing a SPICE solver. I have the following problem: say I put two diodes and a current source in serial (standard diodes). I use MNA and Boost LU-decomposition. The problem is that the nodal matrix becomes very quickly near-singular. I think I have to scale the values but I don't know how and I couldn't find anything on the Internet. Any ideas how to do this scaling?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the perspective of numerical, there is a scale technique for this kind of near-singular matrices. Basically, this technique is to divide each row of A by the sum (or maximum) of the absolute values in that row. You can find KLU which is a linear solver for circuit simulations for more details.

In perspective of SPICE simulation, it uses so-call Gmin stepping technique to iteratively compute and approach a real answer. You can find this in the documents of a SPICE project QUCS (Quite Universal Circuit Simulator).

Answer (score 0):

Scaling does not help when the matrix has both very large and very small entries.

It is necessary to use some or all of the many tricks that were developed for circuit solver applications. A good start is clipping the range of the exponential and log function arguments to reasonable values -- in most circuits a diode forward voltage is never more than 1V and the diode reverse current not less than 1pA.

Actually, look at *all* library functions and wrap them in code that makes their arguments and results suitable for circuit-solving purposes. Simple clipping is sometimes good enough, but it is way better to make sure the functions stay (twice) differentiable and continuous.